# Winforms PictureBox.Load / LoadAsync don't work

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have an xml file with a lot of products (10,000 products up to 200,000 products and even more) and I am trying to write a simple winform that gets this xml file and shows the products images and data:
Here is and xml sample:

```
<catalog>
     <product>
          <name>...</name>
          <price>...</price>
          <description>...</description>
         <imageurl>http://www.boscovs.com/wcsstore/boscovs/images/store/product/thumbnails/60314665830t.jpg</imageurl>
     <product>
     <product>
      ...
     <product>
</catalog>
```

I'm using a backgroung worker for this task so my code looks like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes(...);
     foreach (XmlNode product in xnList)
     {
          PictureBox img = new PictureBox();
          img.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
          img.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 28);
          img.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 94);
          img.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

          //img.LoadAsync(product[...].InnerText);

          img.Load(product[...].InnerText);

          this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
          {
              // Execute the following code on the GUI thread.
              this.Controls.Add(img);
          }));
     }
 }
```

When I use the `img.LoadAsync` I don't see any image and when I'm getting up to image number 1990 out of 8700 and the I'm getting this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in 
System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error creating window handle.
```

When I'm using `img.Load` I sometimes get the image and sometimes I get timeout exception...

This is not a difficult task to do and yet, how can I have a simple code that works ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the problem here is the fact that you are causing a cross-thread call to Load that runs on the UI thread. To avoid the exception you need to call the invoke method, that will dispatch the work to the UI thread:

```
img.Invoke(() => { img.Load(...) });
```

Comment: I'm doing it like this:
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                                    {
                                        tblLoading.Visible = false;

                                        // Execute the following code on the GUI thread.
                                        this.Controls.Add(tblProduct);
                                    }));

Comment: Have you tried to call the use the `Invoke` approach on the `img.Load` method, too?

Comment: no, because I'm creating the PictureBox inside the background worker.

Comment: I got this exception : `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created`. but still, I'm creating the PictureBox inside the background worker... so there is no problem there. Isn't it ?

Comment: " I'm creating the PictureBox inside the background worker..." Well, that's presumably your problem. You should only create WinForms controls and forms on the UI thread.